# Finding the difference between consecutive rows in MySQL without LAG?

Tags: mysql, sql

For each month (except January) I would like to find the difference in quantity from the previous month.

I have a table:

| Month | Qty |
| --- | --- |
| January | 4 |
| February | 3 |
| March | 9 |
| April | 3 |
| May | 7 |

and I would like to return:

| Month | Difference |
| --- | --- |
| February | -1 |
| March | 6 |
| April | -6 |
| May | 4 |

I'm using an older version of MySQL, so I can't use LEAD/LAG for this.

Comment: Do you have only 12 rows in the table, 1 for each month?

Comment: Yes, but this data is a summary of transaction data that has the columns of ID and Datetime. The task is to count the transactions per month and then find the difference between months.

Comment: Post your actual data.

Comment: Do you always have a row for any preceding month or can there be gaps? What should be done if there's a gap? Do you also have a column with the year?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.`Month`, COALESCE(t1.Qty - t2.Qty, 'Unknown') Difference
FROM table t1
LEFT JOIN table t2 
    ON STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t1.`Month`, ' 01 2021'), '%M %d %Y')
     = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(t2.`Month`, ' 01 2021'), '%M %d %Y') + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the previous value.  If the first column is really ordered, then you can use:

```
select t.*, (qty - prev_qty) as difference
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.qty
              from t t2
              where t2.month < t.month
              order by t2.month desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_qty
      from t
     ) t
where prev_qty is not null;
```

If you are really storing months as a string name, then you need to convert to something orderable:

```
select t.*, (qty - prev_qty) as difference
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.qty
              from t t2
              where str_to_date(concat(t2.month, ' 1 2000', '%M %d %Y') < str_to_date(concat(t.month, ' 1 2000', '%M %d %Y')
              order by str_to_date(concat(t2.month, ' 1 2000', '%M %d %Y') desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_qty
      from t
     ) t
where prev_qty is not null;
```